# Get all years between two dates in python

Tags: python, date

Let say that I have this code:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

startDate = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%d.%m.%Y') # e.g. 05.06.2001 DD.MM.YYYY
endDate   = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[2], '%d.%m.%Y') # e.g. 25.05.2005
```

How to get all the years between these two dates, including start and end year, like

```
[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
range(startDate.year, endDate.year+1)
```

Comment: About as simple as it gets. Good solution. +1

Comment: It does not yield all years between startDate and endDate.

Comment: It yields a range so you could do something like `[y for y in range(startDate.year, endDate.year + 1)]` if you're after a list of years

Comment: coming here 8 years later, a fantastically simple solution. Well done!

Comment: great answer, even after all this time